# C# - namespace GestureEventArgs assembly

Tags: c#, assemblies

I've been on this for a couple of days, maybe the answer is in front of me, but I just can't figure it out. I'm kind of a newbie.

I'm trying to use the namespace

```
    `using System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs`
```

On this msdn page: [GestureEventArgs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.gestureeventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) I see that the assembly I'm supposed to reference is *System.Windows.dll*. After doing this, VS 2010 still doesn't recognize *GestureEventArgs*.

This is my top of page:

`using System

    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Linq;

    using System.Text;

    using System.Windows.Input;

    using System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs;`

(I was going to post an image but not enough reputation points :P )

I've already referenced the assembly `System.Windows` I think. It is already inside the *References* folder.

Thank you in advance,

Francisco Santiago

Comment: Is this a Silverlight project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GestureEventArgs` is only available in Silverlight.  Is your project a Siverlight project?

Also, you only need `using System.Windows.Input`, *not* `using System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs`

Comment: Oh boy. That could be a problem. It's a WPF project. I'm developing an application for Kinect and I was browsing some pre-made code, and they use the GestureEventArgs. This poses a serious problem. Thank you for your answer. I don't understand how I didn't stumble upon this information before.

Thank you Pakman, this answers my question.